# Which one have better data retention, data reliability, and durability for long time use? USB Thumb Drive (Sandisk) or Hard Drive (WD Blue 2.5")?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, hardware-failure

Both encrypted with veracrypt (full enceyption)

Sandisk 64GB Usb Flash Drive in metal build. Fuve years warranty.

WD Blue 1TB 2.5" with enclosure (as external drive). Two years warranty.

And if failure happen in future. Which one have better chance to "safe" uncorrupted data?

Comment: The hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an element of luck involved, but the hard drive will likely be more reliable.

SD cards (as opposed to SSD's) generally have minimum circuitry and thus read/write cycles and ability to recover from failure. Warrantys are typically on the basis " it makes it look reliable, but who will be able to find the receipt and bother to return it..." so not a good predictor.

While hard drives have moving parts and absolutely do fail, you are more likely to get some warning of failure.

Comment: Thinking about this more, it depends on application.  If the drive is going to be moved around a lot, the usb one will likely be better because it doesnt have moving parts. I'd use a flash drive over hdd in my car MP3 player any day.

Comment: all the drive will stay in closet and desk in my room. never bring it outside. or maybe will but only once / several years

Comment: Per https://www.lenovo.com/nz/en/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-5-series-laptops/Legion-5-15ACH6H/p/82JU00R4AU (it will be the same for usb drives) Simple Flash drives dont have great durability when not plugged in to power periodically.

Comment: how about dvd? flash drive vs dvd?

Comment: A decent DVD by a mile.  Especially if you crank up the error correction.  Be mindful that DVD readers are getting harder to get and may eventually be a problem. USB is not going anywhere.

Comment: A DVD can be expected to last over 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple flash drives.

If the 64Gb is enough capacity, mirror your content across 3-4 drives and replace them immediately when they fail. This redundancy will beat any single drive.

This is really a math issue.

Assume your Flash drives have an abysmal reliability rate of only 75% over a year. Guess what kind of reliability 4 redundant drive gives you?
80%? 90%? 95%?

Nope. It is a massive 99.6%.

```
0.25 ^ 4 = chance of all 4 failing at the same time = 0.00390625.

1 - 0.00390625 = 0.99609375

or 99.6%
```

Even 3 drives will give you 98.4%, not to mention it can actually protect against lost and theft because you have multiple copies.

And of course, I've never had flash drives that have such abysmal failure rates. Multiple flash drives will beat out a single hard drive hands down.

Comment: unfortunately, for some reasons, i cant do that... if I able to make redundan copies, I will use two hard drive, 1 flash drive, 1 dvd, and 3 clouds. But again, for some reason I cant. Only can choose one, hard drive OR flash drive